# Connecting a django-registration signal

Tags: django, django-registration

I have a function:

```
def create(sender, **kw):
  [...]
```

Which should be called when the user_activated signal from django-registration is called.

I connect the signal and the function using this:

```
from registration.signals import user_activated
[...]
post_save.connect(create, sender=user_activated, dispatch_uid="users-atactivation-signal")
```

But the function isn't called when a user clicks on the activation link, which he got by email.

What do I miss here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A function like this:

```
def create(sender, user, request, **kwarg):
[...]
```

and a connect call like this:

```
user_activated.connect(create)
```

does the job. I have these in my signals.py file.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the same thing here but I couldn't get it to work, my code are here . Kindly check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430937/connecting-a-django-registration-signal

Comment: Also, "@receiver" decorator looks fine as connect() replacement. More info https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#django.dispatch.receiver

Answer (score 2):

If the django-registration app wasn't actually installed, but rather just copied into a project your code that listens for signals won't get called properly.

From the django-registration v0.8 [documentation](http://docs.b-list.org/django-registration/0.8/faq.html#troubleshooting):

> I’ve got functions listening for the registration/activation signals,
>   but they’re not getting called!
>
> The most common cause of this is placing django-registration in a
>   sub-directory that’s on your Python import path, rather than
>   installing it directly onto the import path as normal. Importing from
>   django-registration in that case can cause various issues, including
>   incorrectly connecting signal handlers. For example, if you were to
>   place django-registration inside a directory named django_apps, and
>   refer to it in that manner, you would end up with a situation where
>   your code does this:
>
> `from django_apps.registration.signals import user_registered`
>
> But django-registration will be doing:
>
> `from registration.signals import user_registered`
>
> From Python’s point
>   of view, these import statements refer to two different objects in two
>   different modules, and so signal handlers connected to the signal from
>   the first import will not be called when the signal is sent using the
>   second import.
>
> To avoid this problem, follow the standard practice of installing
>   django-registration directly on your import path and always referring
>   to it by its own module name: registration (and in general, it is
>   always a good idea to follow normal Python practices for installing
>   and using Django applications).

Answer (score 0):

`user_activated` is itself is a Signal. So you have to send itself, with parameters. It requires 2 arguments apart from sender, i.e. user, request

```
user_activated.send(sender=Foo, user=request.user, request=request)
```

`Foo` is the backend class used to activate the user.

Comment: Call me stupid, but I don't get it. I thought I have to connect the signal with a function to call. If I do what you said, Foo would be "user_activated", right? But then where do I put the function to call?
I might have a big missunderstanding of signals work, maybe you can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Is the code that connects the signal-handling method to that signal definitely being loaded? (You can test with a print statment immediately after it). You can make sure you load your signal handlers for a given app by importing them from that app's `__init__.py`:

`from nameofapp.nameoffilewithhandlersinit import *`

PS. is that a typo in the dispatch_uid, or a deliberate name?