# django-registration send email when user is set as active

Tags: django, django-registration

I have a use case, for which [django-registration](https://django-registration.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html) provides most of the required functionality. I need to do something "extra" though. By default `django-registration` supports this workflow:

> 1. A user signs up for an account by supplying a username, email address and password.
> 2. From this information, a new User object is created, with its `is_active` field set to `False`. Additionally, an activation key is generated and stored, and an email is sent to the user containing a link to click to activate the account.
> 3. Upon clicking the activation link, the new account is made active (the `is_active` field is set to `True`); after this, the user can log in.

I need to send a "getting started" email after (or as part of) Step 3; i.e. when a user account becomes "active" (i.e. when "activation" is "complete" from a django-registration standpoint).

How do I insert this within the workflow above? I would like to use `django-registration` and avoid reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`django-registration` provides the `user_activated` signal (read [here](https://django-registration.readthedocs.org/en/latest/signals.html#registration.signals.user_activated)).

The signal should be intercepted using the following code:

```
from registration.signals import user_activated
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(user_activated)
def my_callback(sender, user, request):
    # handle signal
```

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the same thing here but I couldn't get it to work, my code are here . Kindly check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430937/connecting-a-django-registration-signal